# Java: downloading issue using BufferedInputStream, BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, download

When downloading a rar file from the internet with the code below, the downloaded file is larger than it actually is.
Not sure what causes this?

```
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        eventBus.fireEvent(this, new DownloadStartedEvent(item));

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer);
        }

        eventBus.fireEvent(this, new DownloadCompletedEvent(item));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing a full buffer to the output with every write, even if the `read(byte[])` operation didn't completely fill it.

Also, since you are reading into a `byte[]` already, the buffered streams are just counter-productive overhead. Use buffered streams with the single-byte `read()` and `write()` methods.

Here is a better pattern to follow.

```
InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
try {
  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
  try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    while (true) {
      int n = is.read(buffer);
      if (n < 0)
        break;
      os.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    os.flush();
  } finally {
    os.close();
  }
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the call to BufferedOutputStream write that takes a length

`bos.write(buffer, 0, read)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel: use the [Jakarta Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library, which has already implemented (and debugged!) this code. Specifically, look at [IOUtils.copy()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Oh yeah, as *erickson* shows, you need to close your streams after using them. `IOUtils` also has a method to do this.

Comment: yes streams are closed in finally block, but didn't paste it for brevity.
Looking at the commons util, very intresting